# What is calculator package name for Samsung GT-P5100?

Tags: android, android-intent, package, calculator

I used to start built-in calculator activity of Samsung GT-p5100 tablet, but it causes crash. I used this code before for my "HTC Sensation" and that worked for me:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.android.calculator2",
"com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
```

Comment: Launch the activity on the tablet and read the name in Logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for Samsung Galaxy S3 it `com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator`.

Word of caution is that it may change from one OS version to another for Samsung. And of course it will change from one OEM to another. So it may not be a good idea to open a calculator using this method.

Comment: You are welcome! plz accept the answer so that others searching for it might be benefited :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR` Intent category as prescribed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR).

That way it is not device specific.

From the reference:

> public static final String CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR
>
> Since: API Level 15 Used with ACTION_MAIN to launch the calculator
>   application. The activity should be able to perform standard
>   arithmetic operations.
>
> NOTE: This should not be used as the primary key of an Intent, since
>   it will not result in the app launching with the correct action and
>   category. Instead, use this with makeMainSelectorActivity(String,
>   String) to generate a main Intent with this category in the selector.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.category.APP_CALCULATOR"

Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(CALCULATOR_PACKAGE, CALCULATOR_CLASS));
Calculator.this.startActivity(intent);
```

More information [here](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.nl/2012/06/android-open-calculator-from-android.html).

Comment: Looks to me like the wrong answer got ticked here (even after admitting it was the wrong approach to the problem) I vote for this answer to be the solution.

Comment: Thank you. I agree, especially when talking about benefiting future people that encounter this question, but I did not want to bash and look like a greedy rep begger.

Comment: My sentiments entirely, you'll go far.